# Do I need Drive API, or Spreadsheet API, or both?

Tags: gwt, google-drive-api, google-sheets

Currently, I am developing a web-app in GoogleWebToolkit (ie. java back-end) that should:

1. Copy an existing google drive spreadsheet document on the same drive
2. Modify this copied version based on some business logic.

I looked into the Google Spreadsheet API, but had hard time dealing with the oAuth logic. Then I looked at the google Drive API, and found the Dr.Edit example project.

This last project looks good, and I can create and edit text files, but is it now also possible to use some sort of API that reads out SpreadSheet documents instead?

Bottom line is: should i combine Spreadsheet API and Drive API here. What is recommended? I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage files (create/edit/delete/view) with Google Drive SDK but need Spreadsheets API to modify the worksheets, rows and cells individually.

Once you acquire an access token, you can use it to access Spreadsheets endpoints too. Make sure that you're authorizing for the following scope as well:

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is there an example anywhere, on how to parse an incoming file datastream into the Spreadsheet API objects? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: You don't need to download and process files. You can gather metadata about them such as fileId, title and use Spreadsheets API to modify worksheets, rows and cells. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#working_with_worksheets

Comment: aha, so the spreadsheet files are modified in place in Drive, instead of downloaded, modified and reuploaded under a different name?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to download, modify and upload them. Spreadsheets allow you to play with the online files.